# How to delete row in SQLite via ListView in C# for Windows 8 app

Tags: c#, sqlite, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

Here is the code I am using. The item in ListView `AllEventsList` in table `Events` does not gets deleted.

```
private async void DeleteSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var dbpath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "data.db3");
            using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbpath))
            {

                db.Delete<Events>(AllEventsList.SelectedItem.ToString());//selected item



                var d = from x in db.Table<Events>() select x;
                AllEventsList.Items.Clear();
                foreach (var sd in d)
                {
                    AllEventsList.Items.Add(sd.EventName.ToString());
                }

                db.Dispose();
                db.Close();  
            }
            var line = new MessageDialog("Selected Item Deleted");
            await line.ShowAsync();
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

while this works:

```
  db.DeleteAll<Events>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
foreach ( ListViewItem eachItem in AllEventsList.SelectedItems)
{
    AllEventsList.Items.Remove(eachItem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is the `ToString` not giving the value that you expect. Try explicitly passing the primary key value instead, such as:

```
var primaryKey = ((Events)AllEventsList.SelectedItem).YourPrimaryKeyId;
db.Delete<Events>(primaryKey);
```

or you could just call this version of `Delete`, and pass in the entire object:

```
db.Delete(AllEventsList.SelectedItem);
```

Some notes:

- I did not do error condition handling in my code above. You will have to this. For example making sure that there actually is a selected item in the list, otherwise with the code above you will get a null reference exception.
- your calls to `Dispose` and `Close` are redundant. You can remove those because you are already inside of a `using` block.